# Compare sum of values between two specific date ranges over different categories

Tags: pyspark

I'm working in databricks. I have the following dataframe:

```
+----------+---+-----+
|      date|cat|value|
+----------+---+-----+
|2022-08-11|  a|    1|
|2022-08-12|  a|    1|
|2022-08-13|  a|    1|
|2022-08-14|  a|    1|
|2022-08-15|  a|    1|
|2022-08-16|  a|    1|
|2022-08-17|  a|    2|
|2022-08-18|  a|    2|
|2022-08-19|  a|    2|
|2022-08-20|  a|    2|
|2022-08-21|  a|    2|
|2022-08-22|  a|    2|
|2022-08-11|  b|    1|
|2022-08-12|  b|    1|
|2022-08-13|  b|    1|
|2022-08-14|  b|    1|
|2022-08-15|  b|    1|
|2022-08-16|  b|    1|
|2022-08-17|  b|    3|
|2022-08-18|  b|    3|
|2022-08-19|  b|    3|
|2022-08-20|  b|    3|
|2022-08-21|  b|    3|
|2022-08-22|  b|    3|
+----------+---+-----+
```

I want to be able to compare the sum of the values between the 17 and the 22 (week1) and between the 11 and the 16 (week2). Start end and end date of each period are predefined.

So far I've tried something like this:

```
       w = (Window.partitionBy('cat'))

       df = (df
           .withColumn('date', f.to_date('date', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
           .withColumn('value_week_1', 
                      f.when(
                        (f.col('date') >= '2022-08-17') & 
                        (f.col('date') <= '2022-08-22'),
                        f.sum('value').over(w)
                      )
                     )
           .withColumn('value_week_2', 
                       f.when(
                        (f.col('date') >= '2022-08-11') & 
                        (f.col('date') <= '2022-08-16'),
                        f.sum('value').over(w)
                      )
                     )
          )
```

but It doesn't work and I'm not sure I'm going in the right direction.

Ultimately I'd like to have something like this:

```
+----------+---+-----+----+------+--------+
|      date|cat|value|  w1|    w2|    diff|
+----------+---+-----+----+------+--------+
|2022-08-11|  a|    1|   6|    12|       6|
|2022-08-12|  a|    1|   6|    12|       6|
|2022-08-13|  a|    1|   6|    12|       6|
|2022-08-14|  a|    1|   6|    12|       6|
|2022-08-15|  a|    1|   6|    12|       6|
|2022-08-16|  a|    1|   6|    12|       6|
|2022-08-17|  a|    2|   6|    12|       6|
|2022-08-18|  a|    2|   6|    12|       6|
|2022-08-19|  a|    2|   6|    12|       6|
|2022-08-20|  a|    2|   6|    12|       6|
|2022-08-21|  a|    2|   6|    12|       6|
|2022-08-22|  a|    2|   6|    12|       6|
|2022-08-11|  b|    3|  18|    30|      12|
|2022-08-12|  b|    3|  18|    30|      12|
|2022-08-13|  b|    3|  18|    30|      12|
|2022-08-14|  b|    3|  18|    30|      12|
|2022-08-15|  b|    3|  18|    30|      12|
|2022-08-16|  b|    3|  18|    30|      12|
|2022-08-17|  b|    5|  18|    30|      12|
|2022-08-18|  b|    5|  18|    30|      12|
|2022-08-19|  b|    5|  18|    30|      12|
|2022-08-20|  b|    5|  18|    30|      12|
|2022-08-21|  b|    5|  18|    30|      12|
|2022-08-22|  b|    5|  18|    30|      12|
+----------+---+-----+----+------+--------+
```

Comment: What is your window `w` ?

Comment: Looks like one of those long data eng tasks. Lets try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we don't need to use `window` in your case, we can just:

```
df_agg = df\
    .withColumn('week', func.when((func.col('date')>='2022-08-17')&(func.col('date')<='2022-08-22'), func.lit('w1')).otherwise(func.lit('w2')))\
    .groupby('cat').pivot('week')\
    .agg(func.sum('value'))\
    .withColumn('diff', func.col('w2')-func.col('w1'))
```

We can just create a new column called `week` to see if the date is under which week, then create a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

```
w =Window.partitionBy('cat').orderBy('cat')

df1 = (
  #Create week column to help partion. Use row number to create cululative day count. Find each 7th day using pytho's modulo
  df.withColumn('wk',(~(row_number().over(w)%7>0)).cast('int')).withColumn('wk',F.sum('wk').over(Window.partitionBy('cat').orderBy().rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))+1)
  #Finfd the cumulative sum per group per week
  .groupby('cat','wk').agg(F.collect_list('date').alias('date'),F.sum('value').alias('value')).withColumn('date', explode('date'))
#   #Put the total sum in an array in preparation for pivot
.withColumn('value_1', F.collect_set('value').over(Window.partitionBy('cat').orderBy('date','value').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize)))
#   #pivot and create week columns
.withColumn('wk',F.array(F.struct(*[F.col('value_1')[i].alias(f"week_{i+1}")for i in range(2)]))).selectExpr('*','inline(wk)').drop('wk','value_1')
#   #Find the difference
.withColumn('diff', abs(col('week_1')-col('week_2')))
  
).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are somethings about this problem that do not make sense.  Please see end of article for my observations.

[image]

First, the dates from 8/11 to 8/16 do not make up a whole week.  Second, the labels of week-1 being 8/17 to 8/22 and week-2 being 8/11 to 8/16 are logically backwards.

I am going to solve this problem using PySpark and Spark SQL since it is straight forward.

```
#
# Create sample data
#

dat1 = [
("2022-08-11","a",1),
("2022-08-12","a",1),
("2022-08-13","a",1),
("2022-08-14","a",1),
("2022-08-15","a",1),
("2022-08-16","a",1),
("2022-08-17","a",2),
("2022-08-18","a",2),
("2022-08-19","a",2),
("2022-08-20","a",2),
("2022-08-21","a",2),
("2022-08-22","a",2),
("2022-08-11","b",1),
("2022-08-12","b",1),
("2022-08-13","b",1),
("2022-08-14","b",1),
("2022-08-15","b",1),
("2022-08-16","b",1),
("2022-08-17","b",3),
("2022-08-18","b",3),
("2022-08-19","b",3),
("2022-08-20","b",3),
("2022-08-21","b",3),
("2022-08-22","b",3)
]
col1 = ["date", "cat", "value"]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=dat1, schema=col1)
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("sample_data")
```

The above code create a temporary view with the data set.

```
#
# Core data - add category w0
#

stmt = """
select 
  date,
  cat,
  value,
  case 
    when date >= "2022-08-11" and date <= "2022-08-16" then 2
    when date >= "2022-08-17" and date <= "2022-08-22" then 1
    else 0
  end as w0
from sample_data as q1
"""
df2 = spark.sql(stmt)
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("core_data")
```

The code above labels the data as week-1 or week-2 and save this category information as w0.  This could have been hard coded into the dataset above.

```
#
# Pivot data - sum vaule by cat, pivot on w0
#

stmt = """
select * from
(
select cat, w0, value from core_data
)
pivot (
    cast(sum(value) as DECIMAL(4, 2)) as total
    for w0 in (1 w1, 2 w2)
)
"""
df3 = spark.sql(stmt)
df3.createOrReplaceTempView("pivot_data")
```

The code above creates a column per week category and summarizes the values.

[image]

Please note, the result set has 3/5 for cat = b while the original data set has 1/3.  I am using your original data set.

[image]

Last but not least, we join the core_data to the pivot_data and create a calculated column of the difference of (w1-w2).

You can use spark.sql() to create a dataframe and save this result as a file if you want.

To recap, the length of the week categories is not 7 days, labeling a prior week a greater number than the current does not make sense, and the expected result set is wrong in your example since the input set has different numbers.

In short, working with temporary views allows you to leverage your existing T-SQL skills.